# Ansible command inside a playbook with shell module

Tags: ansible

Can I use something as below in ansible:

```
---
- hosts: webserver
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:

    - name: Check ping
      shell: ansible -i localhost.yml  -m shell -a 'ping'
```

That localhost contains all hosts whereas playbook will run on webserver.

Actual  requirement is to run on webserver whereas in one task I need to run a command on all hosts specified in the host file.

Thanks in advance!

Just to add error is :

```
 fatal: [webservice]: FAILED! => {
        "changed": true,
        "cmd": "ansible -i localhost.yml  -m shell -a 'ping'",
        "delta": "0:00:00.009121",
        "end": "2020-02-12 04:47:06.174390",
        "invocation": {
            "module_args": {
                "_raw_params": "ansible -i   localhost.yml -m shell -a 'ping'",
                "_uses_shell": true,
                "argv": null,
                "chdir": null,
                "creates": null,
                "executable": null,
                "removes": null,
                "stdin": null,
                "stdin_add_newline": true,
                "strip_empty_ends": true,
                "warn": true
            }
        },
        "msg": "non-zero return code",
        "rc": 127,
        "start": "2020-02-12 04:47:06.165269",
        "stderr": "ansible: not found",
        "stderr_lines": [
            "ansible: not found"
        ],
        "stdout": "",
        "stdout_lines": [] }
```

Comment: Did you try ? What was the result ? How does it differs from your expectations ?

Comment: It is not working at all. Complaining about ansible could not found. I added the error in the description.

Comment: What is unclear in the error `ansible: not found` ? => install ansible on the remote server(s).

Comment: That's true. It throws an error when this command is run under playbook. If not, it works fine. I'm not sure ansible command can be used inside playbook

Comment: **Any** command can be used inside a `shell` ansible module as long as it is installed on the remote server and in the `$PATH` for the user executing it on the remote server. `ansible` is no exception to that rule. Meanwhile, I don't really get the point of using ansible to run remote ansible commands but that is a totally different story.

Comment: Thanks Zeitounator. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

You want to run an ansible playbook or a shell command inside a server ? 
If you want to run a shell command then don't mention playbook name. If you want to run a playbook then don't mention `-m shell -a` shell parameter.